# What's the difference between a House and a Dynasty?

Tags: differences

Why is it called "House of Plantagenet" or "House of Lancaster", instead of "Dynasty of Plantagenet" or "Dynasty of Lancaster"? What's the difference between *house* and *dynasty*?

Comment: House starred Hugh Laurie. Dynasty starred Joan Collins.

Comment: It's very easy to tell a Tudor house from the Tudor dynasty. Black and white.

Comment: *Dynasty* seems like a special case of *house*. A dynasty is a house that has certain properties, e.g. royalty.

Answer (score 7):

*[House](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/house)* is a only a *dynasty* with reference to its noble family:

> 1.2 A noble, royal, or wealthy family or lineage; a dynasty:

*[Dynasty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dynasty)* refers to the ruling power over a country or some other field of influence:

> noun (plural dynasties)
>
> 1.0 A line of hereditary rulers of a country:
>
> 1.1 A succession of people from the same family who play a prominent role in business, politics, or another field:

In English terminology, the ruling power of a nation can move from *house* to *house*, and the reign of each *house* is referred to as a *dynasty*. The *House of Stuart* enjoyed the *[Stuart Dynasty](http://www.royal.gov.uk/HistoryoftheMonarchy/KingsandQueensoftheUnitedKingdom/TheStuarts/TheStuarts.aspx)* from 1603-1714. The *House of Hanover* extended the *[Hanover Dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Hanover)* from 1714-1901. The *[Windsor Dynasty](http://www.royalty.nu/Europe/England/Windsor/)* began with King George V (formerly Saxe-Coburg-Gotha) and has ruled through the *House of Windsor* in Great Britain to the present.

English seems to use *dynasty* a little more freely for ancient foreign rulers. Kublai Khan, the grandson of Genghis Khan in Mongolia, established the *[Yuan Dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_dynasty)* when he conquered China. The *house of Kahn* ruled in China from 1271 to its collapse in 1368.

The *Empire of the Great Ming* was the last *dynasty* of the ethic Han through Ming Taizu, who ruled from 1368-1398, and established the throne of his grandson Zhu Yunwen before he died. The *house of Ming* ruled in the *[Ming Dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty)* until it was overthrown in 1644.

Nurhaci established the *[Qing Dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty)* in 1644, and the *house of Nurhaci* ruled in China until it was displaced by the communist revolution and the Republic of China in 1912.

Comment: For logical effect, it seems like the British dynasties should be listed before the Chinese.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps it should.

Comment: The Qing Dynasty was displaced by the communist revolution? The republican revolution was communist?

Answer (score 3):

IMO, the stress in "house" is on the **family** connection

> **house**
>
> a family of ancestors, descendants and kindred :  a race of
>   persons from the same stock; especially :  a noble family
>
> *the great houses of England*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

the one in "dynasty" is on genealogy/**lineage in terms of exercising power**:

> a succession of rulers of the same line of descent

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. One ruler to the next, not blood-related : it's a change of dynasty. But one ruler to the next, blood-related though very distantly (nth degree cousin, etc.), or when a sovereign queen takes her husband's name: it's a change of house. Not to mention when the family decides to change name altogether (Saxony Coburg Gotha to self-chosen Windsor).

Examples. Harold to William the Conqueror, it's a change of dynasty. But Anne (Stuart) to George 1st (Hanover), her distant relative, it's a change of house. Likewise, Victoria (born Hanover, spouse Saxony-Coburg-Gotha) to Edward VII, her son : change of house. But Edward VIII to George VI, his brother, no change at all. Do expect a change of house to Mountbatten (also self-translated from original german Battenberg) when Charles (III ?) follows Elizabeth II.